# React app is not rendering at all when loading HTML page that contains it

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I have a small react app that I've built using webpack, it compiled to /dist/bundle.js. I then have an express server to serve an HTML file the references my bundle.js. This way when I connect to my express server it will contain my React app. The HTML file being served by express is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>The Minimal React Webpack Babel Setup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when running locally and opening this in a browser nothing shows. When inspecting the source I can see the HTML file is there, but nothing is showing on the page.

My server.js is the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.listen(8080);
```

Why can't I see my React app? Thanks for any help!

When inspecting the page I see the following (can't really copy & paste so added a screenshot):

[image]

Comment: Just run the console and check if your bundle was loaded.

Comment: @emix I added what I see in the console. It's just the HTML, it references the bundle but doesn't seem to be loading it?

Comment: Actually wait, in the console I see `GET http://localhost:8080/dist/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)` so maybe I have to host the bundle on an express endpoint and reference it from the html that way?

Comment: Here’s your answer, there’s no bundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include access to the static assets on your server.

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));// put the correct folder here
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Kinda realized this as I was working through it. Getting a new error from react now https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=200 but it's definitely a different issue. Seems it's able to load the bundle now.